# Shrink a SQL Anywhere 12 database

Tags: shrink, sybase-sql-anywhere

Is there any way to shrink SQL Anywhere databases?

With SQL Server, it was an easy task. Just do it, have a faster database again that has a size which can be transferred over a slow internet connection.

Can this be achieved with Sybase?

The question is not whether you should shrink or not - it is how it is done. So please don't quote things like "you should not" from Pinal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't shrink SQL Anywhere databases online.

The "correct" way to do it is to unload/reload it in a new database.

It's easy to do it via Sybase Central. Via command line it is the `dbunload` command with the `-an` command line switch. See [Unload utility (dbunload)](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/dbunload.html) in the documentation.

A shrunk database is not by default faster than an "unshrinked" database.

Answer (score 3):

In command line:

```
dbunload -c "UID=username;PWD=password;DBF=DB_old.db" -an "DB_new"
```

- DB_old.db is the name of the original database.
- DB_new.db is the name of the database shrunken.
- "DB_old" and "DB_new" the location of the files is relative to the path of the server that is running.
- If more than one file up the dbspace:

  ```
  DB1_old.db, DB2_old.db, ... DBn_old.db
  ```

  then it is result

  ```
  DB1_new.dbr, DB2_new.dbr .... DBn_new.dbr
  ```

Examples of connection strings are available in the help: [Unload utility (dbunload)](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/dbunload.html)